# Criar uma Trigger com JOIN para duplicar os dados

Tags: mysql, wordpress

```
CREATE TRIGGER `copiadados`AFTER INSERT 
ON `wp_postmeta`
AS
DECLARE @nome NVARCHAR(50),
@email NVARCHAR(50),
@adicional NVARCHAR(255)
SET @nome = (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_appointment_guest_name')
SET @email = (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_appointment_guest_email')
SET @adicional = (SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_cf_meta_value')
INSERT INTO `agendamentos`(post_id, nome, email, dados, data_post) VALUES NEW.@nome, NEW.@email, NEW.@adicional, wp_posts.post_title
INNER JOIN wp_posts on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
```

Esse é o código usado até agora, porém não funcionou.
Estou precisando duplicar os dados para uma nova tabela, pois através dela vou usar os dados para gerar PDF.
Estou usando Wordpress c/ MySQL.

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_title, wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.ID
WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'booked_appointments'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: uma sugestão, ao invés de ter dados duplicados, não poderia criar uma view? estaria sempre atualizada sem a necessidade de ocupar espaço nem duplicar dados

Comment: @RicardoPontual entendo, poderia me dizer por onde começar? rs
A ideia de duplicar os dados é porque o wordpress usa essa tabela para salvar todas as informações, até mesmo as que são de outro plugin e eu queria filtrar apenas as informações desse plugin para poder gerar um PDF com os dados.
Agradeço :D

Comment: Sim posso Richard, consegue montar uma query com os resultados que precisa, usando a tabela `wp_postmeta`? Depois é só salvar essa query como uma `view`

Comment: Ricardo, fiz a query porém tenho uma dúvida.
Estou encaminhando um link com um print da tabela do banco e preciso que ele pegue apenas as informações que estão apontadas no print.
OBS: vou deixar a query no fim da pergunta.
Segue link do print: https://ibb.co/CJVqKzM

Comment: Você consegue dar um `DESCRIBE table_name;` para acrescentar no seu post? Ainda, pode colocar uma linha da tabela mesmo que alterando os dados no post?

Comment: Paulo, acho que consegui entender sua questão. Coloquei o DESCRIBE no post e no comentário acima, coloquei um print dos dados da tabela.

Comment: coloquei um exemplo bem completo e explicativo usando uma view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos por partes. Basicamente sua query seria assim:

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id,
       wp_posts.post_title
  FROM wp_postmeta
 INNER JOIN wp_posts on wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
```

O problema é que, a mesma tabela "wp_postmeta" contém os dados de um mesmo post em diferentes registros, isso requer que se faça um `join` com a própria tabela multiplas vezes, para objter name, email e value, algo assim:

```
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wp_name on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_name.post_id
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wp_email on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_email.post_id
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wp_adicional on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_adicional.post_id
```

Note que como são multiplos joins com propósitos diferentes, cada um tem um *alias* diferente. Além disso, é preciso filtrar pelo "meta_key" para obter os valores corretos, então podemos adicionar a cláusula `WHERE`, assim:

```
 WHERE wp_name.meta_key = '_appointment_guest_name'
   AND wp_email.meta_key = '_appointment_guest_email'
   AND wp_adicional.meta_key = '_cf_meta_value'
```

Aqui usei os diferente *alias* para filtrar o que cada uma deve retornar.
Por fim, para para evitar resultados duplicados, vamos agrupar pelo "post_id". A query completa fica assim:

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id,
       wp_name.meta_value as nome,
       wp_email.meta_value as email,
       wp_adicional.meta_value as adicional,
       wp_posts.post_title
  FROM wp_postmeta
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wp_name on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_name.post_id
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wp_email on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_email.post_id
 INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wp_adicional on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_adicional.post_id
 INNER JOIN wp_posts on wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
 WHERE wp_name.meta_key = '_appointment_guest_name'
   AND wp_email.meta_key = '_appointment_guest_email'
   AND wp_adicional.meta_key = '_cf_meta_value'
 GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id
```

Pode ser vista funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/860125/1

Por fim, colocar isso numa view:

```
CREATE VIEW MinhaView AS
    SELECT wp_postmeta.post_id,
           wp_name.meta_value as nome,
           wp_email.meta_value as email,
           wp_adicional.meta_value as adicional,
           wp_posts.post_title
      FROM wp_postmeta
     INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wp_name on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_name.post_id
     INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wp_email on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_email.post_id
     INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wp_adicional on wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_adicional.post_id
     INNER JOIN wp_posts on wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id
     WHERE wp_name.meta_key = '_appointment_guest_name'
       AND wp_email.meta_key = '_appointment_guest_email'
       AND wp_adicional.meta_key = '_cf_meta_value'
     GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id;
```

E ai fazer um `SELECT * FROM MinhaView`

Pode ver funcionando com a `view` aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a1cfe/2